# Python Regular Expression to search for and print 'apostrophes' (') in output

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to improve this regular expression to search for all words that ends with `t`, including `don't`? I also want to print the whole words, not just the last `t`.

```py
r"\b\w*\Wt\b|\b\w*t\b"
```

I had to write out 2 separate cases for ending with either `t` or `'t`. Or this is the best it could be?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `\b\S*t\b`. It fixes the problem of the engine having to scan a word only to fail to find the non-word character and try the other branch in your pattern. At the very least, swap the two sides of the alternation because the common-case is that the word won't have a contraction.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "mitt cat bat don't foobar"
>>> re.findall(r"\b\S*t\b", s)
['mitt', 'cat', 'bat', "don't"]
```

It's not clear how you want to treat non-word punctuation, but consider a variant that attempts to handle this:

```
>>> s = "mitt cat bat. don't foobar tee t e.t."
>>> re.findall(r"\b\S*t\b", s)
['mitt', 'cat', 'bat', "don't", 't', 'e.t']
>>> re.findall(r"\b[^.,!?\s]*t\b", s)
['mitt', 'cat', 'bat', "don't", 't', 't']
```

Clearly, abbreviations and edge cases may need attention if that's part of your specification.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and examples were really clear. The trick was to swap '\w' with '\S' which makes perfect sense. One can get better by doing more. Thanks again! =]

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on generic patterns if all you want is allow an apostrophe. `\W` matches spaces, too. `\S` matches any characters different from whitespace.

Use

```
r"\b\w+'?t\b"
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/dW5Pd0/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '?                       '\'' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  t                        't'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```